# How to detect if a Java PrintService need a destination file?

Tags: java, file, printing

I have run a Java server process which support printing to a local printer of the server. This work well with a real printer. But is it a software printer like a PDF file printer then it will popup a print dialog on the server and block.

How can I detect if a selected PrintService can only print to a file? The following code sample

```
printService.isAttributeCategorySupported( Destination.class )
```

returns ever true.